# "не" с наречием "всегда"

Tags: орфография

"Не всегда" пишется слитно или раздельно?

Comment: Объясняю: раздельно.  Нет такого слова "невсегда", посмотрите в своём любимом словаре, не найдёте.

Answer (score 3):

> как пишется "не всегда"?

**Раздельно.** См. [**ПАС**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=78#pp78):

> **§ 146**. Отрицание ***не*** пишется **раздельно** в следующих случаях.
>
> <...>
>
> **3**. С местоименными словами, напр.: *не я, не мне, не ты, не тебя, не он, не тот, не мой, не наше, не их, не кто-нибудь, не такой, не
>   каждый, не всякий, не столько, не так, **не всегда**…*

Answer (score 2):

**Не всегда** - раздельное написание, частица НЕ не используется для образования нового слова ("не соединяется" с НЕ).

**Пояснение**

1) Для большинства наречий, **за исключением** наречий на О/Е, образованных от прилагательных (далеко - недалеко), НЕ является отрицательной частицей и пишется **раздельно**: **не всегда,** не там, не так, не здесь, не по-моему, не сегодня.

2) НЕ с наречиями пишется **слитно**, если слово **не употребляется без НЕ** и в некоторых **единичных случаях**, когда НЕ является приставкой:

невпервой, невпопад, нелишне, неподалёку – наречия не употребляются без НЕ;

вдалеке – невдалеке, надолго – ненадолго, кстати – некстати – приставка НЕ используется для образования новых слов.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: *не всегда*. Наречия *невсегда* в русском языке нет.